# Unable to change theme using terminal but can do via Tweaks

Tags: 18.04, themes, cron, gtk3, gsettings

I did

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme Adwaita
```

but nothing happens, except that when I do

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme
```

I do get `Adwaita` (But the theme doesn't change).

But in **GNOME Tweaks** I am able to change it manually.

I would like to do it via terminal so that I can change it with Cron. Any suggestions on what I did wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That key is no longer used in GNOME, window decorations are now dictated by the GTK+ theme.

To check the current theme, run

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme
```

You can use `set` to load your preferred theme.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please tell me where can I find all these key details?

Comment: @Nikhil Try using the GUI application "dconf Editor" to browse and search for keys.